# Multilevel queries on R-trees (Intersection, Union)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, r-tree

Say I have the following setup:

I have a `boost::geometry::index::rtree` that takes as a key a two-dimensional box and as a value a points.
The first dimension of the box, will in practice be applied to (real-valued closed) intervals, whereas the second only to point.

So my box looks like:

```
  using namespace std;
  typedef bg::model::point<unsigned long, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> _pt_t;
  typedef bg::model::box<_pt_t> _box_t;
  typedef pair<_box_t, unsigned long> tree_v_t;
  typedef bgi::rtree<tree_v_t, bgi::quadratic<16> > rtree_t;
```

A box will allways be initialized using:

```
_box_t _mb(unsigned long i, unsigned long s, unsigned long d){
    _box_t b(_pt_t(s, i), _pt_t(s + d, i));
    return b;
  }
```

Now let's say I have initialised the rtree and I want to do two sorts of complicate queries:

1. given a set `si` of intervals`set<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >` and a set `sp` of points `set<unsigned int>`, I would like to iterate all the values that are the result of the following **pseudocode** query:

> ```
> any(si, intersect(rtree_level1)) &&
> any(sp, contains(rtree_level2)) &&
> value in ps
> ```

In other words I want the **subtree** of the rtree that contains the intersection of intervals contained in `si` and of points contained in `sp` and that its values are also in `sp`. If you like you can assume that all intervals in si are disjoint.

2. given a set `spi` of points and intervals `set<unsigned int, pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >`, I would like to iterate all the values that are the result of the following **pseudocode** query:

> ```
> any(spi, intersect(rtree_level1)(spi.interval) && 
>          contains(rtree_level2)(spi.point) &&
>          value in spi.point
>    )
> ```

In other words I want the **union of all subtrees** that come from each element of `spi`, for which they are the **intersection** of the given interval and they **contain** only those points both as keys (second level) and values. This is like the **union** all the R-trees produced from *query 1* if both **si** and **sp** have one element.

I can understand how I can do that using the `satisfy` predicate and applying `transform` to the iterator produced by `qbegin`, but
what is the **most efficient** way to do that in boost?

Comment: What do you mean by "rtree_level1", "rtree_level2 and "subtree"?

What do you mean by `set`? Typically what one would mean would be `std::set`. Is that the case?

How is a `set<unsigned int>` a set of points? Are your points 1-dimensional?

What does this mean: `set<unsigned int, pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >`? `std::set` takes only one type defining `value_type`. Do you mean `std::map` or is this something different?

This looks like a XY-problem. What do you want to achieve in general?

Comment: By set I mean `std::set`. To understand the problem in the general case you can see [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/101386/efficient-data-structure-for-multidimensional-searching-on-intervals-and-keys) post (which was also done by me). `set<unsigned int, pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >` means a set of points where each one is valid for a given interval. Thanks a lot for your interest :)

Comment: `set<unsigned int, pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >` doesn't have sense in the context of `std::set`. What does "a set of points where each one is valid for a given interval" means? That a number is in the interval? Do I understand correctly that your data is 1-dimensional? If that's the case 1d rtree will be equivalent to interval map. Your problem should be considered at a higher level of abstraction than choosing of a specific datastructure for indexing 1d intervals. Which means that this question is XY problem.

Comment: I've read your original post at StackExchange. Do I understand correctly that you have a bidirectional mapping between 1d intervals and some data ([min, max] <-> {key}) and that you want to search both ways? Since both intervals and keys are in different spaces you need 2 separate indexing or sorting mechanisms for them, one for each direction.

Comment: Another thing is this: What if there are 2 overlapping intervals for the same key? Should they be considered as one enlarged interval or are they 2 separate intervals? E.g. should ([1,3]<->'a') and ([2,4]<->'a') be returned as ([1,4]<->'a')? If the intervals should be merged you have to decide if the merging should be done before storing in the index (e.g. rtree) or merged after performing the query for intervals you need.

Comment: The data-structure should always have merged intervals. So inputing ([1,3]<->'a') when you have ([2,4]<->'a') should store ([1,4]<->'a').

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic program with double index (R-tree and std::map) doing bi-directional indexing: from char to box/interval and from box/interval to char:

Includes, `iostream` is needed only for output.

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

Namespaces for convenience.

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
```

Basic bi-directional index allowing to insert box/interval-char pairs and find box based on char or vector of chars based on box (intersecting). `insert()` merges boxes if needed.

```
template <typename Box, typename T>
class rtree_map_index
{
    typedef std::map<T, Box> map_type;
    typedef typename map_type::iterator map_iterator;
    typedef typename map_type::const_iterator map_const_iterator;
    typedef std::pair<Box, map_iterator> rtree_value;
    typedef bgi::rtree<rtree_value, bgi::rstar<4> > rtree_type;

public:
    void insert(Box const& box, T const& v)
    {
        std::pair<map_iterator, bool>
            p = m_map.insert(std::make_pair(v, box));

        map_iterator map_it = p.first;
        T const& map_val = map_it->first;
        Box & map_box = map_it->second;

        // new key,value inserted into map
        if (p.second)
        {
            // insert it to the r-tree
            m_rtree.insert(rtree_value(map_box, map_it));
        }
        // key already exists in map and box has to be expanded
        else if (! bg::covered_by(box, map_box))
        {
            // calculate expanded box
            Box new_box = map_box;
            bg::expand(new_box, box);

            // update r-tree
            m_rtree.remove(rtree_value(map_box, map_it));
            m_rtree.insert(rtree_value(new_box, map_it));

            // update map
            map_box = new_box;
        }
    }

    bool find(T const& v, Box & result) const
    {
        map_const_iterator it = m_map.find(v);
        if (it != m_map.end())
        {
            result = it->second;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void find(Box const& box, std::vector<char> & result) const
    {
        std::vector<rtree_value> res;
        m_rtree.query(bgi::intersects(box), std::back_inserter(res));

        result.resize(res.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
            result[i] = res[i].second->first;
    }

private:
    rtree_type m_rtree;
    map_type m_map;
};
```

Main function with basic use-case.

```
int main()
{
```

for 2-dimentional data stored in the r-tree (boxes).

```
    {
        typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
        typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
        rtree_map_index<box, char> index;

        index.insert(box(point(0, 0), point(3, 3)), 'a');
        index.insert(box(point(1, 1), point(4, 4)), 'a');
        index.insert(box(point(5, 5), point(6, 6)), 'b');

        box res1;
        index.find('a', res1);

        std::cout << bg::wkt(res1) << std::endl;

        std::vector<char> res2;
        index.find(box(point(4, 4), point(5, 5)), res2);

        BOOST_ASSERT(res2.size() == 2);
        std::cout << res2[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << res2[1] << std::endl;
    }
```

for 1-dimensional data stored in the r-tree (intervals)

```
    {
        typedef bg::model::point<double, 1, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
        typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
        rtree_map_index<box, char> index;

        index.insert(box(point(0), point(3)), 'a');
        index.insert(box(point(1), point(4)), 'a');
        index.insert(box(point(5), point(6)), 'b');

        box res1;
        index.find('a', res1);

        std::cout << "(" << bg::get<0, 0>(res1) << ", " << bg::get<1, 0>(res1) << ")" << std::endl;

        std::vector<char> res2;
        index.find(box(point(4), point(5)), res2);

        BOOST_ASSERT(res2.size() == 2);
        std::cout << res2[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << res2[1] << std::endl;
    }
```

The end.

```
    return 0;
}
```

Note that instead of `rtree` you could use `interval_map`. You should be able to build on top of `rtree_map_index`. You could add a constructor creating map and rtree from a container of elements of type `std::pair<Box, T>` to take advantage from r-tree packing algorithm. You could implement whatever `find()` function you need. Etc.